# How to call more than one function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for some reason when I call all four functions at once I get an error with the newly named dataframes. specifically the empty dataframes that I want to fill. Have no idea why. I've tried to move all empty dataframes outside the function and that didn't work. Any help appreciated.

The first function works (FID_extract1_to_9) , but the final three do not.

The error:

> new_dfa[colname] = selected_data
>
> NameError: global name 'new_dfa' is not defined

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/GC_results')


def FID_extract1_to_9(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern) #finds all files with ending in 00* in the file path
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files] 

    new_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:16]  
        new_df[colname] = selected_data
    print new_df 
    new_df.to_csv('FID_11169_liquid.csv') #Enter name of output file here



def FID_extract9_to_96(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]

    new_dfa = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:16]  
        new_dfa[colname] = selected_data
    print new_dfa 
    new_dfa.to_csv('FID_11169_Liquid.csv') 



def TCD_extract1_to_9(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]

    new_dfb = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:16]  
        new_df[colname] = selected_data
    print new_dfb 
    new_dfb.to_csv('TCD_11169_liquid.csv') 



def TCD_extract9_to_96(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]

    new_dfc = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:16]  
        new_dfa[colname] = selected_data
    print new_dfc 
    new_dfc.to_csv('TCD_11169_Liquid.csv') 



FID_extract1_to_9('C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/FID_00*') #files directory

FID_extract9_to_96('C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/FID_0*')

TCD_extract1_to_9('C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/TCD_00*')

TCD_extract9_to_96('C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/TCD_0*')
```

Comment: But in your last 2 functions the local temp df names are `new_dfb` but you use `new_df` and in the last one it's `new_dfc` but you use `new_dfa`

Comment: Ah, my error. Need to pay more attention. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Many i ask a quick question. I have 96 columns, But i want columns of 12... so effectively 8 rows with columns of 12. Is this possible?

Comment: It depends, it should be a separate question, you could use `concat` potentially

Comment: I'm trying to concat the dataframes created by each function but I get NameError. Is this to do with accessing the result from outside of the function itself?

Comment: Well your dfs are local to the functions but you then return them which means you need to append each to a list and then you can concat. If it's not this then it should be a separate question after you accept an answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a basic syntax error in your function `def TCD_extract1_to_9(filepath)` you declare `new_dfb = pd.DataFrame()` but you then use `new_df[colname] = selected_data`.

In your last function `def TCD_extract9_to_96(filepath)` you declare `new_dfc = pd.DataFrame()` but then use `new_dfa[colname] = selected_data`.

So you need to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion ,
If your output is going to be csv, then your code looks complicated. Just use the csv module, import csv.

```
with open("path to save", "wb") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows("the data")
```

this is easy and will fetch u no errors.

Comment: The OP is performing some calculations on the dataframe and then outputting to csv, your suggestion doesn't address this